# Sync Salesforce contact on iphone rubrica

Tags: contact, einstein, salesforce-for-outlook, inbox, einstein-activity-capture

I'm trying to Sync Salesforce contacts (or a custom obj that is our real contact) and some fields of this obj on the standard iPhone rubrica.

My main goal is: open my iphone standard rubrica and see name, email, Phone number and inside the Note field a concat of some CRM text fields.

- Lightning sync isn't available anymore https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_sync_admin_overview.htm&type=5.
- Salesforce for Outlook lost support in 2024 https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.outlookcrm_sfo_about.htm&type=5
- Salesforce inbox requires a separate app
- Einstein captures activity sync contacts with an email account.

Furthermore, all those products work with the Contact std obj and do not take in account a custom one.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "rubrica"?  Please [edit] your post to clarify what this is.

Comment: A rubrica Is the Place where you store all your phone numbers. Also called address book, and on iPhone this Is the icone https://images.app.goo.gl/SmAydnUFgV1xphkv5